# output of dbms_xplan.display_awr() is coming blank

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, database-performance, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

I want to see plan output of below query.

```
explain plan for
SELECT /*AJAY*/ MAIN_QUERY.CIRCLE_NAME,
          MAIN_QUERY.OPERATOR_ID,
          MAIN_QUERY.OPERATOR_NAME,
          (DECODE(MAIN_QUERY.BILLING_TYPE,'1','Energy','2','IPF','3','IPF-Opex',MAIN_QUERY.BILLING_TYPE)) BILLING_TYPE,
          (DECODE( MAIN_QUERY.BILLING_CYCLE,1,'Monthly',2,'Monthly Advance', 4,'Quarterly Advance',MAIN_QUERY.BILLING_CYCLE)) BILLING_CYCLE,
          (DECODE(MAIN_QUERY.BILLING_CYCLE,4,TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(MAIN_QUERY.BILL_MONTH,'YYYYMM'),'Mon-yyyy')||'-'||TO_CHAR(ADD_MonTHS(TO_DATE(MAIN_QUERY.BILL_MONTH,'YYYYMM'),2),'Mon-YYYY'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(MAIN_QUERY.BILL_MONTH,'YYYYMM'),'Mon-yyyy')))BILL_MONTH,
          MAIN_QUERY.BILL_CYCLE_NO,
          MAIN_QUERY.EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID INVOICE_NO,
          (CASE WHEN 1= 0 THEN '0'
           ELSE
             DECODE(MAIN_QUERY.CURRENT_LEVEL,NULL,'Level 1','0','0','-999','Closed',(SELECT LEVEL_NAME FROM MST_LEVEL WHERE LEVEL_ID = MAIN_QUERY.CURRENT_LEVEL))
           END) CURRENT_LEVEL, --1.3
          --MAIN_QUERY.TOTAL_SITES, MAIN_QUERY.SITES_NOT_BILLED, MAIN_QUERY.SITES_BILLED, MAIN_QUERY.INVOICE_AMT,
          MAIN_QUERY.TOTAL_SITES,
          ( SELECT /*+ INDEX(T1,IDX_BILL_MONTH) */  COUNT(1) FROM TXN_EBS_DETAILS T1 WHERE T1.BILL_MONTH = MAIN_QUERY.BILL_MONTH AND T1.BILLING_CYCLE = MAIN_QUERY.BILLING_CYCLE AND  T1.OPERATOR_ID = MAIN_QUERY.OPERATOR_ID AND T1.BILLING_TYPE = 1 and T1.CONSUMPTION_FLAG = '00002') SITES_NOT_BILLED, --1.7
          MAIN_QUERY.SITES_BILLED, --MAIN_QUERY.INVOICE_AMT,
          ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.INVOICE_AMT,2) INVOICE_AMT, --2.2
          MAIN_QUERY.COL_APRVD_NM, MAIN_QUERY.COL_APRVD_CNT, --MAIN_QUERY.COL_APRVD_TTL_AMT, 
          ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_APRVD_TTL_AMT,2) COL_APRVD_TTL_AMT, --2.2
          ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_APRVD_AVG_AMT,2) COL_APRVD_AVG_AMT, --2.1,2.4
          --(CASE WHEN MAIN_QUERY.COL_APRVD_CNT <> 0 THEN ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_APRVD_TTL_AMT/MAIN_QUERY.COL_APRVD_CNT,2) ELSE 0 END ) COL_APRVD_AVG_AMT, --2.1
          --ROUND((CASE WHEN MAIN_QUERY.COL_APRVD_CNT <> 0 THEN ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_APRVD_TTL_AMT/MAIN_QUERY.COL_APRVD_CNT,2) ELSE 0 END ),2) COL_APRVD_AVG_AMT, --2.1, 2.2, 2.4
          MAIN_QUERY.COL_REJ_NM, MAIN_QUERY.COL_REJ_CNT, --MAIN_QUERY.COL_REJ_TTL_AMT, 
          ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_REJ_TTL_AMT,2) COL_REJ_TTL_AMT, --2.2
          ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_REJ_AVG_AMT,2) COL_REJ_AVG_AMT, --2.1, 2.4 
          --(CASE WHEN MAIN_QUERY.COL_REJ_CNT <> 0 THEN ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_REJ_TTL_AMT/MAIN_QUERY.COL_REJ_CNT,2) ELSE 0 END ) COL_REJ_AVG_AMT, --2.1
          --ROUND((CASE WHEN MAIN_QUERY.COL_REJ_CNT <> 0 THEN ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_REJ_TTL_AMT/MAIN_QUERY.COL_REJ_CNT,2) ELSE 0 END ),2) COL_REJ_AVG_AMT, --2.1, 2.2, 2.4
          MAIN_QUERY.COL_DISP_NM, MAIN_QUERY.COL_DISP_CNT, --MAIN_QUERY.COL_DISP_TTL_AMT,
          ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_DISP_TTL_AMT,2) COL_DISP_TTL_AMT, --2.2
          ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_DISP_AVG_AMT,2) COL_DISP_AVG_AMT, --2.1, 2.4
          --(CASE WHEN MAIN_QUERY.COL_DISP_CNT <> 0 THEN ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_DISP_TTL_AMT/MAIN_QUERY.COL_DISP_CNT,2) ELSE 0 END ) COL_DISP_AVG_AMT, --2.1
          --ROUND((CASE WHEN MAIN_QUERY.COL_DISP_CNT <> 0 THEN ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_DISP_TTL_AMT/MAIN_QUERY.COL_DISP_CNT,2) ELSE 0 END ),2) COL_DISP_AVG_AMT, --2.1, 2.2, 2.4
          MAIN_QUERY.COL_PEN_NM, MAIN_QUERY.COL_PEN_CNT, --MAIN_QUERY.COL_PEN_TTL_AMT, 
          ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_PEN_TTL_AMT,2) COL_PEN_TTL_AMT, --2.2
          ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_PEN_AVG_AMT,2)COL_PEN_AVG_AMT, --2.1,2.4 
          --(CASE WHEN MAIN_QUERY.COL_PEN_CNT <> 0 THEN ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_PEN_TTL_AMT/MAIN_QUERY.COL_PEN_CNT,2) ELSE 0 END ) COL_PEN_AVG_AMT, --2.1
          --ROUND((CASE WHEN MAIN_QUERY.COL_PEN_CNT <> 0 THEN ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.COL_PEN_TTL_AMT/MAIN_QUERY.COL_PEN_CNT,2) ELSE 0 END ),2) COL_PEN_AVG_AMT, --2.1, 2.2, 2.4
          NVL(COL_DISP_ER_NM,'Disputed Earlier') COL_DISP_ER_NM,
          NVL(COL_DISP_ER_CNT,0) COL_DISP_ER_CNT,
          --NVL(COL_DISP_ER_TTL_AMT,0) COL_DISP_ER_TTL_AMT,
          ROUND(NVL(COL_DISP_ER_TTL_AMT,0),2) COL_DISP_ER_TTL_AMT, --2.2
          NVL(COL_DISP_ER_AVG_AMT,0) COL_DISP_ER_AVG_AMT, --2.1, 2.4
          --(CASE WHEN NVL(COL_DISP_ER_CNT,0) <> 0 THEN ROUND(NVL(COL_DISP_ER_TTL_AMT,0)/NVL(COL_DISP_ER_CNT,0),2)ELSE 0 END )  COL_DISP_ER_AVG_AMT, --2.1
          --ROUND((CASE WHEN NVL(COL_DISP_ER_CNT,0) <> 0 THEN ROUND(NVL(COL_DISP_ER_TTL_AMT,0)/NVL(COL_DISP_ER_CNT,0),2)ELSE 0 END ),2)  COL_DISP_ER_AVG_AMT, --2.1, 2.2, 2.4
          ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.AVG_BILLAMT_PER_SITE,2) AVG_BILLAMT_PER_SITE, --2.1, 2.4
          --ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.INVOICE_AMT/MAIN_QUERY.SITES_BILLED,2) AVG_BILLAMT_PER_SITE, --2.1 
          --ROUND(MAIN_QUERY.INVOICE_AMT/MAIN_QUERY.SITES_BILLED,2) AVG_BILLAMT_PER_SITE, --2.1 , 2.2, 2.4
          OUTPUT_FILE_PATH,FILE_EXT,
          (SELECT LISTAGG(MR.ROLE_NAME,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY MR.ROLE_ID)
           FROM MST_ROLE MR, MST_ROLE_LEVEL MRL
           WHERE MR.ROLE_ID = MRL.ROLE_ID
           AND MRL.LEVEL_ID = MAIN_QUERY.CURRENT_LEVEL
          ) ROLE_LISTING,
          --DECODE(MAIN_QUERY.BACKBILL_FLAG,'1','Back Bill',NULL) BACKBILL_FLAG, --1.4
          TO_NUMBER(DECODE(MAIN_QUERY.BACKBILL_FLAG,'1',(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TXN_IBILL_CUSTOMER_BACK_BILL T1 WHERE T1.BILL_MONTH = MAIN_QUERY.BILL_MONTH AND T1.BILLING_CYCLE = MAIN_QUERY.BILLING_CYCLE AND  
                    T1.OPERATOR_ID = MAIN_QUERY.OPERATOR_ID AND T1.BILLING_TYPE = 1 AND T1.BACKBILL_FLAG = 1),NULL)) BACKBILL_FLAG, --2.3
          DECODE(MAIN_QUERY.BACKBILL_FLAG,'2','Back Bill','Regular Bill') BACKBILL_TYPE --1.4
          FROM
          (SELECT CIRCLE_NAME, --1.5
           OPERATOR_ID,SF_IBIL_GET_CUSTOMER_NAME(OPERATOR_ID) OPERATOR_NAME,
           BILLING_TYPE,BILLING_CYCLE,MAX(BILL_MONTH)BILL_MONTH, '' BILL_CYCLE_NO,
           EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID,CURRENT_LEVEL,NVL(MAX(TOTAL_SITES),0) TOTAL_SITES,
           NVL(MAX(SITES_NOT_BILLED),0) SITES_NOT_BILLED,
           NVL(MAX(SITES_BILLED),0) SITES_BILLED,
           NVL(MAX(INVOICE_AMT),0) INVOICE_AMT,
           NVL(MAX(BACKBILL_FLAG),0) BACKBILL_FLAG, --1.4  -- 1.6
           NVL(MAX(AVG_BILLAMT_PER_SITE),0) AVG_BILLAMT_PER_SITE, --2.1, 2.4
           NVL(MAX(COL_APRVD_NM),'Approved') COL_APRVD_NM,
           NVL(MAX(COL_APRVD_CNT),0) COL_APRVD_CNT,
           NVL(MAX(COL_APRVD_TTL_AMT),0) COL_APRVD_TTL_AMT,
           NVL(MAX(COL_APRVD_AVG_AMT),0) COL_APRVD_AVG_AMT,
           NVL(MAX(COL_REJ_NM),'Rejected') COL_REJ_NM,
           NVL(MAX(COL_REJ_CNT),0) COL_REJ_CNT,
           NVL(MAX(COL_REJ_TTL_AMT),0) COL_REJ_TTL_AMT,
           NVL(MAX(COL_REJ_AVG_AMT),0) COL_REJ_AVG_AMT,
           NVL(MAX(COL_DISP_NM),'Disputed') COL_DISP_NM,
           NVL(MAX(COL_DISP_CNT),0) COL_DISP_CNT,
           NVL(MAX(COL_DISP_TTL_AMT),0) COL_DISP_TTL_AMT,
           NVL(MAX(COL_DISP_AVG_AMT),0) COL_DISP_AVG_AMT,
           NVL(MAX(COL_PEN_NM),'Pending') COL_PEN_NM,
           NVL(MAX(COL_PEN_CNT),0) COL_PEN_CNT,
           NVL(MAX(COL_PEN_TTL_AMT),0) COL_PEN_TTL_AMT,
           NVL(MAX(COL_PEN_AVG_AMT),0) COL_PEN_AVG_AMT
           FROM
             (SELECT CIRCLE_NAME, --1.5
              OPERATOR_ID,BILLING_TYPE,BILLING_CYCLE,BILL_MONTH,
              EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID,CURRENT_LEVEL,BACKBILL_FLAG, --1.4
              COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY OPERATOR_ID,BILLING_TYPE,BILLING_CYCLE,BILL_MONTH) TOTAL_SITES,
              NULL SITES_NOT_BILLED,NULL SITES_BILLED,NULL INVOICE_AMT,
                      NULL AVG_BILLAMT_PER_SITE, --2.1, 2.4
              NULL COL_APRVD_NM,NULL COL_APRVD_CNT,NULL COL_APRVD_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_APRVD_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_REJ_NM,NULL COL_REJ_CNT,NULL COL_REJ_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_REJ_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_DISP_NM,NULL COL_DISP_CNT,NULL COL_DISP_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_DISP_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_PEN_NM,NULL COL_PEN_CNT,NULL COL_PEN_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_PEN_AVG_AMT
              FROM TXN_EBS_DETAILS --TOTAL_SITES
              WHERE REPROCESS_FLAG=0 --1.8
              UNION

              SELECT CIRCLE_NAME, --1.5
              OPERATOR_ID,BILLING_TYPE,BILLING_CYCLE,BILL_MONTH,
              NULL EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID,CURRENT_LEVEL,BACKBILL_FLAG, --1.4
              NULL TOTAL_SITES,
              COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY OPERATOR_ID,BILLING_TYPE,BILLING_CYCLE,BILL_MONTH) SITES_NOT_BILLED,
              NULL SITES_BILLED,NULL INVOICE_AMT, 
              NULL AVG_BILLAMT_PER_SITE, --2.1, 2.4
              NULL COL_APRVD_NM,NULL COL_APRVD_CNT,NULL COL_APRVD_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_APRVD_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_REJ_NM,NULL COL_REJ_CNT,NULL COL_REJ_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_REJ_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_DISP_NM,NULL COL_DISP_CNT,NULL COL_DISP_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_DISP_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_PEN_NM,NULL COL_PEN_CNT,NULL COL_PEN_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_PEN_AVG_AMT
              FROM TXN_EBS_DETAILS TED
              WHERE TED.CONSUMPTION_FLAG = '00002' --SITES_NOT_BILLED

              UNION

              SELECT CIRCLE_NAME, --1.5
              OPERATOR_ID,BILLING_TYPE,BILLING_CYCLE,BILL_MONTH,
              EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID,CURRENT_LEVEL,BACKBILL_FLAG, --1.4
              NULL TOTAL_SITES,NULL SITES_NOT_BILLED,
              COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) SITES_BILLED,
              SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) INVOICE_AMT,
              ROUND(AVG(TOTAL_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) ,2) AVG_BILLAMT_PER_SITE, --2.1, 2.4
              NULL COL_APRVD_NM,NULL COL_APRVD_CNT,NULL COL_APRVD_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_APRVD_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_REJ_NM,NULL COL_REJ_CNT,NULL COL_REJ_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_REJ_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_DISP_NM,NULL COL_DISP_CNT,NULL COL_DISP_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_DISP_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_PEN_NM,NULL COL_PEN_CNT,NULL COL_PEN_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_PEN_AVG_AMT
              FROM  TXN_EBS_DETAILS
              WHERE EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID IS NOT NULL  --SITES_BILLED

              UNION

              SELECT CIRCLE_NAME, --1.5
              OPERATOR_ID,BILLING_TYPE,BILLING_CYCLE,BILL_MONTH,
              EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID,CURRENT_LEVEL,BACKBILL_FLAG, --1.4
              NULL TOTAL_SITES,NULL SITES_NOT_BILLED,
              NULL SITES_BILLED,NULL INVOICE_AMT,
              NULL AVG_BILLAMT_PER_SITE, --2.1, 2.4
              'Approved' COL_APRVD_NM,
              COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) COL_APRVD_CNT,
              SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) COL_APRVD_TTL_AMT,
              ROUND(AVG(TOTAL_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) ,2) COL_APRVD_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_REJ_NM,NULL COL_REJ_CNT,NULL COL_REJ_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_REJ_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_DISP_NM,NULL COL_DISP_CNT,NULL COL_DISP_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_DISP_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_PEN_NM,NULL COL_PEN_CNT,NULL COL_PEN_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_PEN_AVG_AMT
              FROM   TXN_EBS_DETAILS
              WHERE  APPROVAL_FLAG NOT IN (0,-100)
              AND BILL_APPROVAL_FLAG = '0'
              AND EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID IS NOT NULL --APPROVED

              UNION

              SELECT CIRCLE_NAME, --1.5
              OPERATOR_ID,BILLING_TYPE,BILLING_CYCLE,BILL_MONTH,
              EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID,CURRENT_LEVEL,BACKBILL_FLAG, --1.4
              NULL TOTAL_SITES,NULL SITES_NOT_BILLED,
              NULL SITES_BILLED,NULL INVOICE_AMT,
              NULL AVG_BILLAMT_PER_SITE, --2.1, 2.4
              NULL COL_APRVD_NM,NULL COL_APRVD_CNT,NULL COL_APRVD_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_APRVD_AVG_AMT,
              'Rejected' COL_REJ_NM,
              COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) COL_REJ_CNT,
              SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) COL_REJ_TTL_AMT,
              ROUND(AVG(TOTAL_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) ,2) COL_REJ_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_DISP_NM,NULL COL_DISP_CNT,NULL COL_DISP_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_DISP_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_PEN_NM,NULL COL_PEN_CNT,NULL COL_PEN_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_PEN_AVG_AMT
              FROM   TXN_EBS_DETAILS
              WHERE  APPROVAL_FLAG = 0
              AND BILL_APPROVAL_FLAG = '1'
              AND EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID IS NOT NULL --REJECTED

              UNION

              SELECT CIRCLE_NAME, --1.5
              OPERATOR_ID,BILLING_TYPE,BILLING_CYCLE,BILL_MONTH,
              EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID,CURRENT_LEVEL,BACKBILL_FLAG, --1.4
              NULL TOTAL_SITES,NULL SITES_NOT_BILLED,
              NULL SITES_BILLED,NULL INVOICE_AMT,
              NULL AVG_BILLAMT_PER_SITE, --2.1, 2.4
              NULL COL_APRVD_NM,NULL COL_APRVD_CNT,NULL COL_APRVD_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_APRVD_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_REJ_NM,NULL COL_REJ_CNT,NULL COL_REJ_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_REJ_AVG_AMT,
              'Disputed' COL_DISP_NM,
              COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) COL_DISP_CNT,
              SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) COL_DISP_TTL_AMT,
              ROUND(AVG(TOTAL_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) ,2) COL_DISP_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_PEN_NM,NULL COL_PEN_CNT,NULL COL_PEN_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_PEN_AVG_AMT
              FROM  TXN_EBS_DETAILS
              WHERE  APPROVAL_FLAG = -100
              AND EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID IS NOT NULL      --DISPUTED

              UNION

              SELECT CIRCLE_NAME, --1.5
              OPERATOR_ID,BILLING_TYPE,BILLING_CYCLE,BILL_MONTH,
              EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID,CURRENT_LEVEL,BACKBILL_FLAG, --1.4
              NULL TOTAL_SITES,NULL SITES_NOT_BILLED,
              NULL SITES_BILLED,NULL INVOICE_AMT,
              NULL AVG_BILLAMT_PER_SITE, --2.1, 2.4
              NULL COL_APRVD_NM,NULL COL_APRVD_CNT,NULL COL_APRVD_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_APRVD_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_REJ_NM,NULL COL_REJ_CNT,NULL COL_REJ_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_REJ_AVG_AMT,
              NULL COL_DISP_NM,NULL COL_DISP_CNT,NULL COL_DISP_TTL_AMT,NULL COL_DISP_AVG_AMT,
              'Pending' COL_PEN_NM,
              COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) COL_PEN_CNT,
              SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) COL_PEN_TTL_AMT,
              ROUND(AVG(TOTAL_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) ,2) COL_PEN_AVG_AMT
              FROM TXN_EBS_DETAILS
              WHERE  APPROVAL_FLAG = 0
              AND BILL_APPROVAL_FLAG = '0'
              AND EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID IS NOT NULL --PENDING
           )
           GROUP BY CIRCLE_NAME, --1.5
           OPERATOR_ID,BILLING_TYPE,BILLING_CYCLE,   --1.4  -- 1.6 BACKBILL_FLAG,
           --BILL_MONTH,
           EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID,CURRENT_LEVEL
           HAVING MAX(EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) IS NOT NULL
           ORDER BY BILL_MONTH DESC, OPERATOR_NAME, EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID DESC --1.6
           ) MAIN_QUERY,

          (SELECT OPERATOR_ID,BILLING_TYPE,BILLING_CYCLE,BILL_MONTH,
           'Disputed Earlier' COL_DISP_ER_NM,
           COL_DISP_ER_CNT,COL_DISP_ER_TTL_AMT,
           ROUND(COL_DISP_ER_TTL_AMT/COL_DISP_ER_CNT,2) COL_DISP_ER_AVG_AMT
           FROM (SELECT OPERATOR_ID,BILLING_TYPE,BILLING_CYCLE,BILL_MONTH,
                        SUM(COL_DISP_ER_CNT) COL_DISP_ER_CNT,
                        SUM(COL_DISP_ER_TTL_AMT) COL_DISP_ER_TTL_AMT
                   FROM
                    (SELECT OPERATOR_ID,BILL_MONTH,BILLING_TYPE,BILLING_CYCLE,
                            COUNT(1) COL_DISP_ER_CNT,
                            SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) COL_DISP_ER_TTL_AMT
                       FROM TXN_EBS_DETAILS
                      WHERE EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID IS NULL
                        AND (APPROVAL_FLAG = -100 OR (APPROVAL_FLAG = 0 AND BILL_APPROVAL_FLAG = '2'))

                     GROUP BY OPERATOR_ID,BILL_MONTH,BILLING_CYCLE,BILLING_TYPE,CURRENT_LEVEL
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT Y.OPERATOR_ID,Y.BILL_MONTH,Y.BILLING_TYPE,Y.BILLING_CYCLE,
                            COUNT(1) COL_DISP_ER_CNT,
                            SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) COL_DISP_ER_TTL_AMT
                       FROM TXN_EBS_DETAILS Y,
                    (SELECT T.EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID,T.BILL_MONTH,T.OPERATOR_ID,T.BILLING_CYCLE,
                            T.BILLING_TYPE,T.L1
                       FROM (SELECT EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID,BILL_MONTH,OPERATOR_ID,
                                    BILLING_CYCLE,BILLING_TYPE,
                                    LEAD(EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY OPERATOR_ID,BILL_MONTH,BILLING_CYCLE ORDER BY EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID) L1
                               FROM TXN_EBS_DETAILS
                              WHERE EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID IS NOT NULL) T
                      WHERE T.EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID <> T.L1) F
                     WHERE F.L1 = Y.EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID
                       AND F.OPERATOR_ID = Y.OPERATOR_ID
                       AND F.BILL_MONTH = Y.BILL_MONTH
                       AND F.BILLING_CYCLE = Y.BILLING_CYCLE
                       AND F.BILLING_TYPE = Y.BILLING_TYPE
                       AND Y.RFB_FLAG = '1' --1.9
                     GROUP BY Y.OPERATOR_ID,Y.BILL_MONTH,Y.BILLING_TYPE,
                              Y.BILLING_CYCLE,Y.EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID
                              )
                 GROUP BY OPERATOR_ID,BILL_MONTH,BILLING_CYCLE,BILLING_TYPE)
          ) DISP_ER_QUERY,
          MST_CUST_TEMPLATE MCT,
          MST_REPORT_TEMPLATE MRT
          WHERE MAIN_QUERY.OPERATOR_ID = DISP_ER_QUERY.OPERATOR_ID(+)
            AND MAIN_QUERY.BILL_MONTH = DISP_ER_QUERY.BILL_MONTH(+)
            AND MAIN_QUERY.BILLING_CYCLE = DISP_ER_QUERY.BILLING_CYCLE(+)
            AND MAIN_QUERY.BILLING_TYPE = DISP_ER_QUERY.BILLING_TYPE(+)
            --AND MAIN_QUERY.BACKBILL_FLAG = DISP_ER_QUERY.BACKBILL_FLAG(+) --1.9
            AND MAIN_QUERY.OPERATOR_ID = MCT.CUSTOMER_ID(+)
            AND MCT.TEMP_ID = MRT.TEMP_ID(+)
            AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TXN_EBS_DETAILS TED
                         WHERE TED.EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID = MAIN_QUERY.EXTERNAL_INVOICE_ID
                           AND TED.STARTING_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-2014','DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31-JAN-2017','DD-MON-YYYY')
                           AND ROWNUM < 2);
```

when i am running this query on sqldeveloper, it giving me correct output (with say n no. of rows).

but when i am doing 
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_awr() );

(sql-id of my query from v$sql).

PLAN_OUTPUT_TABLE COLUMN SHOWING NO RECORD/OUTPUT.

can anybody help? Am i missing any step in using this proc dbms_xplan.display_awr(). my query is correct since it giving output

Comment: Are you certain that the query plan for this statement was captured in the AWR?  You would normally use that to look at older information and `display_cursor` to view information about a query that is in the cursor cache.  That seems more likely if you are running this immediately after running the query.

Comment: Yes @JustinCave , i am running this immediately after running query, but what do you mean by older information w.r.t query execution.

Comment: The AWR (assuming you are configured to use it) captures the most expensive queries in each snapshot interval and stores it for a period of time.  Normally the snapshot interval is something like 30 minutes but can be as short as 15 minutes and the retention interval is normally something like 30 or 60 days.  If you're looking for the query plan of a very expensive query that was running at 1pm last week, the AWR would be the place to look.  It's not the place to look for a query you ran 5 seconds ago.

Comment: thanks justin for sharing the info. :)

Comment: So what is the place to look for a query I ran 5 seconds ago? I tried SELECTing from gv$sql_plan but the DISPLAY_AWR output is so much better.